# Batch renaming files with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename

How can Bash rename a series of packages to remove their version numbers? I've been toying around with both `expr` and `%%`, to no avail.

Examples:

`Xft2-2.1.13.pkg` becomes `Xft2.pkg`

`jasper-1.900.1.pkg` becomes `jasper.pkg`

`xorg-libXrandr-1.2.3.pkg` becomes `xorg-libXrandr.pkg`

Comment: I intend to use this regularly, as a write-once use-a-lot script.

Any system I'll be using will have bash on it, so I'm not afraid of the bashisms that are quite handy.

Comment: More generally see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash

Comment: For the record, this was a fine question in 2009; but these days, "gimmeh codez" questions are not well-received on Stack Overflow, so probably don't regard this as a good example of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You could use bash's parameter expansion feature

```
for i in ./*.pkg ; do mv "$i" "${i/-[0-9.]*.pkg/.pkg}" ; done
```

Quotes are needed for filenames with spaces.

Comment: I like it too, but it uses bash-specific features... I normally don't use them in favor of "standard" sh.

Comment: For throwaway one-line interactive stuff I always use this instead of sed-fu. If it were a script, yep, avoid bashisms.

Comment: One issue I've found with the code: What happens if the files were already renamed and I run it again?  I get warnings for trying move into a subdirectory of itself.

Comment: To avoid re-run errors, you can use the same pattern in the "*.pkg" part, ie  "for i in *-[0-9.]*.pkg ; do mv $i ${i/-[0-9.]*.pkg/.pkg} ; done". But the errors are innocuous enough (moving to the same file).

Comment: Not a bash solution, but if you have perl installed, it provides the handy rename command for batch renaming, simply do `rename "s/-[0-9.]*//" *.pkg`

Comment: [My recent answer elsewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49099627/874188) has a remark on how the glob pattern `-[0-9.]*` might not mean what you think or hope.

Comment: Update on this answer for recursive go: ```for i in ls **/*.pkg ; do mv "$i" "${i/-[0-9.]*.pkg/.pkg}" ; done```

Comment: What is the technical term / man page where I can look up the details of the replacement business in `{i/-[0-9.]*.pkg/.pkg}` ?

Comment: It would be nice if someone could explain what the "${i/-[0-9.]*.pkg/.pkg}" jargon does. Elsewise this answer is of little help for others who don't have the exact same need as the OP.

Comment: @patrick `man bash`

Comment: @Sergio To understand the bash parameter expansions, see https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-bash-shell-parameter-expansions.

Comment: @patrick These are [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). The dollar sign in `${i/-[0-9.]*.pkg/.pkg}` is part of the expression. There is a bunch of these `${variable (special character) something}` constructions in the linked reference manual.

Comment: ${inputString/findThisStringOrPattern/replaceWithThisString} explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210909/1087499)

Answer (score 39):

If all files are in the same directory the sequence

```
ls | 
sed -n 's/\(.*\)\(-[0-9.]*\.pkg\)/mv "\1\2" "\1.pkg"/p' | 
sh
```

will do your job.  The *sed* command will create a sequence of *mv* commands, which you can then pipe into the shell.  It's best to first run the pipeline without the trailing `| sh` so as to verify that the command does what you want.

To recurse through multiple directories use something like

```
find . -type f |
sed -n 's/\(.*\)\(-[0-9.]*\.pkg\)/mv "\1\2" "\1.pkg"/p' |
sh
```

Note that in *sed* the regular expression grouping sequence is brackets preceded by a backslash,  `\(` and `\)`, rather than single brackets `(` and `)`.

Comment: Forgive my naïvety, but wouldn't escaping the parentheses with backslashes make them be treated as literal characters?

Comment: In sed the regular expression grouping sequence is \(, rather than a single bracket.

Comment: didn't work for me, would be glad to get your help.... The suffix of the FROM file is appended to the TO file: $find . -type d | sed -n 's/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)anysoftkeyboard\(.*\)/mv "\1\/\2anysoftkeyboard\3" "\1\/\2effectedkeyboard\3"/p'|sh >>>>>>>OUTPUT>>>> mv: rename ./base/src/main/java/com/anysoftkeyboard/base/dictionaries to ./base/src/main/java/com/effectedkeyboard/base/dictionaries/dictionaries: No such file or directory

Comment: You seem to be missing the backslash in the brackets.

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) The first variety can be achieved with `printf '%s\n' * | sed ...` and with some creativity you can probably get rid of the `sed` too. Bash's `printf` offers a `'%q'` format code which could come in handy if you have filenames which contain literal shell metacharacters.

Comment: Handling newlines embedded in file names is a noble goal. But the output of `printf` will still fail in this case. It will also fail if the expanded file names don't fit in the command's argument vector. So the approach based on `printf` is even less robust.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis' first comment appears to have degraded over time; it's supposed to say `sed` without the non-standard `-E` or `-r` option requires a backslash before grouping parenthesis. I guess the markdown rendering in comments has changed over the years.

Answer (score 13):

I'll do something like this:

```
for file in *.pkg ; do
    mv $file $(echo $file | rev | cut -f2- -d- | rev).pkg
done
```

supposed all your file are in the current directory. If not, try to use find as advised above by Javier.

**EDIT**: Also, this version don't use any bash-specific features, as others above, which leads you to more portability.

Comment: They are all in the same directory.

What do you think of rq's answer?

Comment: I like not to use bash-specific features, but more standard sh instead.

Comment: I assumed this was for a quicky rename, not for writing the next generation cross platform, portable Enterprise Application ;-)

Comment: Haha, fair enough... Just out of a portability-minded man like me :)

Comment: This one doesn't account for the third example:  xorg-libXrandr (hyphen used in name).

Comment: Nerdling: I'm sorry to disagree, but of course it works for the third example. Please, try the code if you don't believe me.

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem was.  I ran yours after I ran rq's code.  I'll try it again.

Comment: Alright, cool.  Yours works as well (with same side effects as rq — he has a solution for that in his comments).

Comment: This has serious quoting errors; try https://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 10):

I find that `rename` is a much more straightforward tool to use for this sort of thing. I found it on Homebrew for OSX

For your example I would do:

```
rename 's/\d*?\.\d*?\.\d*?//' *.pkg
```

The 's' means substitute. The form is  `s/searchPattern/replacement/ files_to_apply`. You need to use regex for this which takes a little study but it's well worth the effort.

This is the fairly popular [Perl-based `rename` utility](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_perl_oneliners/perl-rename-command.html); there is another with the [same name but different syntax and features in the `util-linux` package](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) and probably several more.

Comment: I agree. For an occasional thing, using `for` and `sed` etc. is fine, but it's much simple and quicker to just use `rename` if you find yourself doing this often.

Comment: Is that you escaping periods?

Comment: The problem is that this is not portable; not only  do not all platforms have a `rename` command; in addition, some will have a *different* `rename` command with different features, syntax, and/or options. This looks like the Perl `rename` which is fairly popular; but the answer should really clarify this.

Comment: Installing rename on ubuntu/debian `sudo apt-get install rename` RedHat derived distros: `sudo dnf install prename` OSX: `brew install rename`

Comment: @AttilaFulop That's nice, but what would be nicer still would be an overview of the differences between incompatible `rename` utilities and a way to figure out which one you have.

Answer (score 8):

We can assume `sed` is available on any *nix, but we can't be sure
it'll support `sed -n` to generate mv commands. (**NOTE:** Only GNU `sed` does this.)

Even so, bash builtins and sed, we can quickly whip up a shell function to do this.

```
sedrename() {
  if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    sed_pattern=$1
    shift
    for file in $(ls $@); do
      mv -v "$file" "$(sed $sed_pattern <<< $file)"
    done
  else
    echo "usage: $0 sed_pattern files..."
  fi
}
```

## Usage

```
sedrename 's|\(.*\)\(-[0-9.]*\.pkg\)|\1\2|' *.pkg

before:

./Xft2-2.1.13.pkg
./jasper-1.900.1.pkg
./xorg-libXrandr-1.2.3.pkg

after:

./Xft2.pkg
./jasper.pkg
./xorg-libXrandr.pkg
```

## Creating target folders:

Since `mv` doesn't automatically create target folders we can't using
our initial version of `sedrename`.

It's a fairly small change, so it'd be nice to include that feature:

We'll need a utility function, `abspath` (or absolute path) since bash
doesn't have this build in.

```
abspath () { case "$1" in
               /*)printf "%s\n" "$1";;
               *)printf "%s\n" "$PWD/$1";;
             esac; }
```

Once we have that we can generate the target folder(s) for a
sed/rename pattern which includes new folder structure.

This will ensure we know the names of our target folders.  When we
rename we'll need to use it on the target file name.

```
# generate the rename target
target="$(sed $sed_pattern <<< $file)"

# Use absolute path of the rename target to make target folder structure
mkdir -p "$(dirname $(abspath $target))"

# finally move the file to the target name/folders
mv -v "$file" "$target"
```

Here's the full folder aware script...

```
sedrename() {
  if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    sed_pattern=$1
    shift
    for file in $(ls $@); do
      target="$(sed $sed_pattern <<< $file)"
      mkdir -p "$(dirname $(abspath $target))"
      mv -v "$file" "$target"
    done
  else
    echo "usage: $0 sed_pattern files..."
  fi
}
```

Of course, it still works when we don't have specific target folders
too.

If we wanted to put all the songs into a folder, `./Beethoven/` we can do this:

## Usage

```
sedrename 's|Beethoven - |Beethoven/|g' *.mp3

before:

./Beethoven - Fur Elise.mp3
./Beethoven - Moonlight Sonata.mp3
./Beethoven - Ode to Joy.mp3
./Beethoven - Rage Over the Lost Penny.mp3

after:

./Beethoven/Fur Elise.mp3
./Beethoven/Moonlight Sonata.mp3
./Beethoven/Ode to Joy.mp3
./Beethoven/Rage Over the Lost Penny.mp3
```

## Bonus round...

Using this script to move files from folders into a single folder:

Assuming we wanted to gather up all the files matched, and place them
in the current folder, we can do it:

```
sedrename 's|.*/||' **/*.mp3

before:

./Beethoven/Fur Elise.mp3
./Beethoven/Moonlight Sonata.mp3
./Beethoven/Ode to Joy.mp3
./Beethoven/Rage Over the Lost Penny.mp3

after:

./Beethoven/ # (now empty)
./Fur Elise.mp3
./Moonlight Sonata.mp3
./Ode to Joy.mp3
./Rage Over the Lost Penny.mp3
```

## Note on sed regex patterns

Regular sed pattern rules apply in this script, these patterns aren't
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions).  You could have sed
extended regular expression syntax, using either `sed -r` or `sed -E`
depending on your platform.

See the POSIX compliant `man re_format` for a complete description of
sed basic and extended regexp patterns.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a POSIX near-equivalent of the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602770/874188). This trades the Bash-only `${variable/substring/replacement}` parameter expansion for one which is available in any Bourne-compatible shell.

```
for i in ./*.pkg; do
    mv "$i" "${i%-[0-9.]*.pkg}.pkg"
done
```

The parameter expansion `${variable%pattern}` produces the value of `variable` with any suffix which matches `pattern` removed. (There is also `${variable#pattern}` to remove a prefix.)

I kept the subpattern `-[0-9.]*` from the accepted answer although it is perhaps misleading. It's not a regular expression, but a glob pattern; so it doesn't mean "a dash followed by zero or more numbers or dots". Instead, it means "a dash, followed by a number or a dot, followed by anything". The "anything" will be the shortest possible match, not the longest. (Bash offers `##` and `%%` for trimming the longest possible prefix or suffix, rather than the shortest.)

Answer (score 3):

better use `sed` for this, something like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pkg" |
 sed -e 's/((.*)-[0-9.]*\.pkg)/\1 \2.pkg/g' |
 while read nameA nameB; do
    mv $nameA $nameB;
 done
```

figuring up the regular expression is left as an exercise (as is dealing with filenames that include spaces)

Comment: Thanks: Spaces are not used in the names.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work assuming that

- everything ends with $pkg
- your version #'s always start with a "-"

strip off the .pkg, then strip off -..

```
for x in $(ls); do echo $x $(echo $x | sed 's/\.pkg//g' | sed 's/-.*//g').pkg; done
```

Comment: There are some packages that have a hyphen in their name (see third example).  Does this impact your code?

Comment: You can run multiple sed expressions using `-e`. E.g. `sed -e 's/\.pkg//g' -e 's/-.*//g'`.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [quote your variables.](/q/10067266) See also http://shellcheck.net/ for diagnosing common problems and antipatterns in shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple `*.txt` files to be renamed as `.sql` in same folder. 
below worked for me:

```
for i in \`ls *.txt | awk -F "." '{print $1}'\` ;do mv $i.txt $i.sql; done
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by abstracting it to the OP's actual use-case.

Comment: This has multiple problems as well as an apparent syntax error. See http://shellcheck.net/ for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this answers. I also had some sort of problem. Moving .nzb.queued files to .nzb files. It had spaces and other cruft in the filenames and this solved my problem:

```
find . -type f -name "*.nzb.queued" |
sed -ne "s/^\(\(.*\).nzb.queued\)$/mv -v \"\1\" \"\2.nzb\"/p" |
sh
```

It is based on the answer of Diomidis Spinellis.

The regex creates one group for the whole filename, and one group for the part before .nzb.queued and then creates a shell move command. With the strings quoted. This also avoids creating a loop in shell script because this is already done by sed.

Comment: Should be noted that this is only true for GNU sed.  On BSDs sed will not interpret the `-n` option in the same way.

Comment: @ocodo Why do you say that? The `-n` option is completely standard and [even supported by POSIX `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Comment: Looks like I was very wrong about that!