# How to make a reference to what was matched in glob pattern

Tags: bash, unix, glob

With regexes you can put a capturing group and refer to it in your action (i.e. \1).  Is there something similar for when glob is used in bash?

Say I have files named 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', and I want to rename them to 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'.  I'd like to do something like this:

mv file(?) foo\1

is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for batch renaming.  There are a lot of solutions here on stackoverflow.  Here is [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602706/batch-renaming-with-bash)

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this particular problem:

```
for i in `ls | egrep "^file[0-9]?$"`; do mv $i ${i/file/ foo}; done
```

Comment: Thanks, similar to the link in the marked answer, and 'ls | egrep PATTERN' is useful when you need the power of regex to list the files you want to affect.