# Remove the specific filename extension in a filename in the directory using sed

Tags: sed

How can I remove a specific filename extension in the filename in a directory using sed. Like for example I have a files in a directory,

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.cpp
```

Then I want to remove the filename extension of a file with .txt extension, so the result is,

```
file1
file2
file3.cpp
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/252239/how-can-i-batch-rename-files-in-bash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602706/batch-renaming-with-bash

Comment: What if you already have a file named "file1"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename`:

```
rename 's/\.txt$//' *
```

Saying so would remove the `.txt` extension from matching files.

Answer (score 1):

And if you really want to use sed, this should work:

```
    for file in *.txt ; do mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)\.txt/\1/'` ; done
```