# rename each file found in multiple subfolders from "xxx_xxx.jpg" to "xxx-xxx.jpg" format

Tags: bash

I am new to bash shell programming and need help on this

I have a directory "production\new\images\sp" which contains multiple sub-folders with multiple file name in this format "xxxxx_xxxxx.jpg".  I like to rename each of the file name from this format to "xxxxx-xxxxx.jpg" format in each sub-folder.

example:

```
86193730_43134.jpg =====> 86193730-43134.jpg
```

Comment: `find`, `tr`, `mv`. Have you tried something with those 3?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/602770/1009730) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/602840/1009730)

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
rename 's/_/-/' *_*.jpg
```

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: actually, `s/_/-/` :) EDIT: aaa, fixed

Comment: You can use `rename _ -` or (on Debian derivatives) `rename.ul _ -`, that way you're not excluding all non-Debian distros.

Comment: how to use that for multiple files in multiple sub-folders? like \test\subfolder1; \test\subfolder2; test\subfolder3, etc....

Comment: If you want it to be recursive, use [tag:bash4] and `shopt -s globstar; rename 's/x/x/' **/*_*.jpg`. Or just `rename 's///' */*/*_*.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

In case rename is not available (as on OSX):

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -execdir bash -c 'f="{}"; nf=$(tr "_" "-" <<< "$f") && mv "$f" "$nf"' \;
```

Comment: what is this mean nf=$(tr "_" "-" <<< "$f") && mv "$f" "$nf"

Comment: `nf=$(tr "_" "-" <<< "$f")` translates `_` by `-` in filename and `mv "$f" "$nf" ` renames old file with new filename

Comment: Hi anubhava,Will it work for multiple sub-folders? Will it works in bash?

Comment: Yes ofcourse it works in BASH and solution will work in multiple sub folders

Answer (score -1):

this works for me (improved by @sputnik):

```
for f in *_*.jpg; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/_/-/')" ; done
```

Comment: -1 Don't do this. Never parse `ls` output, use globs directly : `for f in *_*.jpg`

Comment: Added quotes to prevent _bash word spliting_