# Renaming multiple files in a folder in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, file-rename

I have some multiple files in a folder I want to shorten the names. Here are the input files

Input

```
S_12_O_319_K27ac_S12818.sorted.bam
S_12_O_319_K27me3_S12815.sorted.bam
S_12_O_319_K4me1_S12816.sorted.bam
S_12_O_319_K4me3_S12817.sorted.bam
S_14_AS_11_K27ac_S12843.sorted.bam
S_14_AS_11_K27me3_S12840.sorted.bam
S_14_AS_11_K4me1_S12841.sorted.bam
S_14_AS_11_K4me3_S12842.sorted.bam
S_12_O_319_K27ac_S12818.sorted.bam.bai
S_12_O_319_K27me3_S12815.sorted.bam.bai
S_12_O_319_K4me1_S12816.sorted.bam.bai
S_12_O_319_K4me3_S12817.sorted.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K27ac_S12843.sorted.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K27me3_S12840.sorted.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K4me1_S12841.sorted.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K4me3_S12842.sorted.bam.bai
```

Output

```
S_12_O_319_K27ac.bam
S_12_O_319_K27me3.bam
S_12_O_319_K4me1.bam
S_12_O_319_K4me3.bam
S_14_AS_11_K27ac.bam
S_14_AS_11_K27me3.bam
S_14_AS_11_K4me1.bam
S_14_AS_11_K4me3.bam
S_12_O_319_K27ac.bam.bai
S_12_O_319_K27me3.bam.bai
S_12_O_319_K4me1.bam.bai
S_12_O_319_K4me3.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K27ac.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K27me3.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K4me1.bam.bai
S_14_AS_11_K4me3.bam.bai
```

Note that my files have two different extensions, one is *.bam another is *.bam.bai. I want to rename of all of them at once to shorten the name. Remove the portion `_S12843.sorted` from all of them. Note that this is the 5th underscore while the number following `_S12843` is different for different files. Only similar pattern is the string `sorted`. So would like to truncate that entire portion to shorten the name. How can I achieve that with a bash or rename or sed . Any help would be appreciated. I am able to remove the string with sorted but not the numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Renaming with Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602706/batch-renaming-with-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rename` utility you can do:

```
rename 's/_[^_.]+\.sorted//' *.sorted.*
```

If you don't have `rename` then use this `for` loop:

```
for f in *.sorted.*; do
   mv "$f" "${f/_S[[:digit:]]*.sorted}"
done
```

Comment: Both of them works, the prefer the one in loop as it is consuming less time. I did not new this `[:digit:]` thing. Can you please explain this to me once.

Comment: `[[:digit:]]` is POSIX property to match a digit `[0-9]` in glob or regex patterns

Comment: ah ok the only problem was then identifying the `_S` ideally this should also work `for f in *.sorted.*; do mv "$f" "${f/_S[[0-9]]*.sorted}"; done`

Comment: note that this is the _perl script_ `rename` found in Debian/Ubuntu and their derivatives, but not necessarily present on other non-Debian based Linux boxes such as Arch Linux, CentOS, Slackware, etc, on those boxes I believe util-linux's rename is used.  __tl;dr__ you cannot depend on the behavior of rename.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)_[^_.]*\.[^.]*(.*)/mv "&" "\1\2"/e' file
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)_[^_.]*\.[^.]*(.*)/mv "&" "\1\2"/' file | shell
```

where `shell` could be `bash` etc