# Batch move and rename files with bash

Tags: bash

I have lots of files in a structure like this. There are `.py` files inside folder with the name `std01`...`std60`

```
/std01 (directory)
    problem1.py
    problem2.py
    problem3.py
/std02 (directory)
    problem1.py
    problem2.py
    problem3.py
```

By using `bash` commands, can I move and rename those files, so that it would be in a folder by the file name, leading by the `std` folder name?

```
/problem1.py (directory)
    std01_problem1.py
    std02_problem1.py
    ...
/problem2.py (directory)
    std01_problem2.py
    std02_problem2.py
    ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch renaming files with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602706/batch-renaming-files-with-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for std in *; do
    for problem in "$std"/*; do
        problem=${std##*/}    # trim directory name
        mkdir -p "$problem"   # create dir if it doesn't already exist
        mv "$std/$problem" "$problem/$std_$problem"
    done

    rmdir "$std"   # if original directory is empty, remove it
 done
```

Comment: Should `${file##*/}` be `${std##*/}`? And is this better than using `basename`?

Comment: Actually, avoiding an external process is usually preferable.

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

Before:

```
$ tree std*
std01
├── problem1.py
├── problem2.py
└── problem3.py
std02
├── problem1.py
├── problem2.py
└── problem3.py
```

---

```
find . -type f -path "*std[0-9]*/problem[0-9]*.py" -exec bash -c \
'IFS=/ read -ra a <<<"$1"; mkdir -p "${a[-1]}"; mv "$1" "${a[-1]}/${a[-2]}_${a[-1]}"' _ {} \;
```

---

After:

```
$ tree problem*
problem1.py
├── std01_problem1.py
└── std02_problem1.py
problem2.py
├── std01_problem2.py
└── std02_problem2.py
problem3.py
├── std01_problem3.py
└── std02_problem3.py
```