# Remove last 10 characters from list of files in current directory

Tags: bash, sed

I have around 255 files in the current directory. A list of some of them is

```
ALLT042194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_001434_0084
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0083
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0084
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0089
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0085
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0082
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0060
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0044
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0064
ALLT194_TAB20.tsv_20180117_0094
```

I want to remove all chars after `.tsv`. For this I have used the code below. In the code I am removing the last 14 characters, so I am getting the file name up through `.tsv`. But my code is giving output for 15 files only and removing the rest of the files from the 255.

```
for i in *
do
  j=`echo $i | sed -e 's/..............$//'`
  mv $i $j
done
```

How can I remove everything after `.tsv`?

Comment: Your code has some quoting errors which http://shellcheck.net/ will helpfully point out to you. But the basic problem is that the file names are not unique if you remove the stuff after `.tsv` and so your code is doing exactly what you are saying you want it to do -- it's moving a number of files to the same name, with most iterations ending up replacing a file you have previously moved to the same name. The real problem seems to be that you *actually* want something else. We can't guess what that is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/602770/4486184

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with correct quoting:

```
for original_filename in *; do
  mv "$original_filename" "${original_filename%.tsv*}.tsv"
done
```

- See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal for information on the parameter expansion used, and others available.
- See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes on how an why to quote parameter expansions.

N.B: As pointed out by @tripleee, you will overwrite most files by doing that.

Comment: Please find a suitable duplicate instead of posting new answers which duplicate existing answers.

Comment: Also `"${original_filename%.tsv}"` is not correct here; you need to trim everything after `.tsv` too.

Comment: Indeed, edited.
What am I supposed to do with a suitable duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/602770/4486184 is similar but not the same answer,  do you think I should mark it as duplicate nonetheless?

Comment: At your privilege level you can only add a comment but if you put a comment like "Possible duplicate of (URL)" it will be picked up as a proposed duplicate if others with more rep want to vote to close as dupe. Five close votes by users with the required privilege (3k+ rep) and it will be closed.